# Deserializing JSON with Jackson - Why JsonMappingException "No suitable constructor"?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a problem deserializing a JSON string using Jackson (but I have no problem serializing an object to JSON).

Below I present the classes I use. The problem comes when I rececive a JSON-string (a ProtocolContainer that was serialized elsewhere and retrieved via webservice) and want to de-serialize it:

JSON-string:

> {"DataPacketJSONString":null,"DataPacketType":"MyPackage.DataPackets.LoginRequestReply","MessageId":6604,"SenderUsername":null,"SubPacket":{"__type":"LoginRequestReply:#MyPackage.DataPackets","Reason":"Wrong pass or username","Success":false,"Username":"User1"}}

I try to deserialize like this:

```
ProtocolContainer ret = ProtocolContainer.Create(jsonString);
```

and the code that executes in ProtocolContainer can be seen below. The exception:

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor
>   found for type [simple type, class
>   MyPackage.ProtocolContainer]: can not
>   instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) 
>   at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4059dcb0; line: 1, column: 2]

**ProtocolContainer.java - a container class that encapsulates my "SubPackets":**

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import MyPackage.DataPackets.*;

public class ProtocolContainer 
{
    public String SenderUsername;
    public String DataPacketType;
    public long MessageId;
    public String DataPacketJSONString;
    public DataPacket SubPacket;

    public ProtocolContainer(DataPacket dp)
    {
        DataPacketType = dp.getClass().toString().substring(6);
        SubPacket = dp;
    }

    public String toJSON()
    {
        try {
            if (SubPacket != null)
                this.DataPacketJSONString = ProtocolContainer.mapper.writeValueAsString(SubPacket);

            return ProtocolContainer.mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static ProtocolContainer Create(String jsonString)
    {
        ProtocolContainer pc = null;
        try {
            pc = mapper.readValue(jsonString, ProtocolContainer.class); // error here!
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();  // Exception when deserializing
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try 
        {
            if (pc != null && pc.DataPacketType == "LoginRequest")
                pc.SubPacket = mapper.readValue(jsonString, LoginRequest.class);
    }
        catch (JsonParseException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (JsonMappingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pc;
    }
}
```

**DataPacket.java - a superclass for all my datapackets**

```
public class DataPacket 
{

}
```

**LoginRequestReply.java - a DataPacket**

```
package MyPackage.DataPackets;

import MyPackage.DataPacket;

public class LoginRequestReply extends DataPacket
{
    public boolean LoginOK;
    public int UserId;
}
```

Comment: Follow-up: After some messing about, I am not getting the following error:
*JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class MyPackage.ProtocolContainer] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method*. If I add a constructor that takes a String, then no error but the Object is "empty"... I dont think it should be necessary to add implementation support in the constructor. **How should I fix this?**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The error messages says it all, your ProtocolContainer does not have a default constructor so Jackson is unable to create an instance of it. (Since the only current way of creating a ProtocolContainer is by passing in a DataPacket.)

Comment: yes, I added an empty constructor. Its weird, cause I got another error before, when I had an empty constructor... Anyways, this particular issue is resolved... no i have to deal with the "__type" thing that .NET adds on serialization...

Comment: Hmm, so the error is back, sort of. Now I get this:
*JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class MyPackage.ProtocolContainer] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method*. If I add a constructor that takes a String, then no error but the Object is "empty"... I dont think it should be necessary to add implementation support in the constructor...

Comment: I forgot to put the default constructor, now it works, thanks  ^^

Answer (score 15):

In this case, you could add `@JsonCreator` annotation to constructor. There are two ways it could be done:

- If you only add that annotation, then the whole matching JSON is first bound to type of the only argument (`DataPacket'). I assume you do not want to do that.
- If you also add `@JsonProperty` annotation before the argument, then JSON property matching that name is passed to constructor (annotation is mandatory because Java byte code does NOT contain name of method or constructor arguments) -- I suspect you want `@JsonProperty("SubPacket")`

This works if necessary information for constructor comes from JSON. If not, you do need to add alternate no-arg constructor.

By the way, the error message does sound wrong in this case. It should only be given if JSON data matching expected value if a JSON String.

Answer (score 2):

**Thumb Rule**: Add a default constructor for each class you used as a mapping class. You missed this and issue arise!

Simply add a default constructor and it should work.

Comment: None of the above answers are correct, the only thing that worked for me was

 public ConsolidationUserAndManagerCredentialsRequest() {
  super () ;
 }

Without the `super()` nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the issue and none of the answers worked for me. it seems the exception thrown is very generic one and is thrown for n number of causes. So one fix may not work for everyone.
My case:
we have a json response in which creditcard is a complex type but optional. when there is no creditcard data, we were getting an empty string in response:

"creditcard":""

But Credit card is a complex type for us:

```
<xs:element name="CC" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="aaa" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xs:element name="bbb" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xs:element name="ccc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
```

We figured out, if there is no creditcard data, we should have something like this in json response:

"creditcard":{}

and not "creditcard":""

it fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility if you use **Lombok**! I haven't found out the reason.

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public Car implements Serializable {
   Map<String, Object> basicInfo;
   CarEnums.TypeEnum type;
   List<Maintenance> maintenances;
   public void addMaintenance(Maintenance m) {
      // initialize if null
      maintenances.add(m);
   }

   // must be static or jackson throws "inner class cannot be static" exception.  Yes you see it right. 
   public static class Maintenance { 
      private Long id;
      public class Maintenance(Long id) { // constructor causes the exception
         this.id = id;
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

If lombok constructor annotation is used at outer class, the inner class even if one writes all args constructor manually, it still complains the constructor cannot be found. If you use `@AllArgsConstructor` on `Maintenance` instead of writing your own, jackson would deserialise successfully. I got the same experience today, adding `@AllArgsConstructor` solves it.