# How to define an enum in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, openapi

Does anyone know how to define possible `enum` values in an OpenAPI 2.0 definition so that they will be displayed in the Model tab of Swagger UI?
 [Example here](https://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/addPet) has an enum option for the `status` property.
 How to do define such an enum in OpenAPI 2.0?

Answer (score 97):

"enum" works like this in OpenAPI 2.0:

```json
      {
        "in": "query",
        "name": "sample",
        "description": "a sample parameter with an enum value",
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [ "1", "2"],
        "required": true
      }
```

and in OpenAPI 3.0:

```json
      {
        "in": "query",
        "name": "sample",
        "description": "a sample parameter with an enum value",
        "schema": {
          "type": "string",
          "enum": [ "1", "2"]
        },
        "required": true
      }
```

As you can see, there's a query parameter called `sample` of type string, and has an enum stating two possible values. In this case, the sample states the parameter is required, so the UI will not show an empty value as an option.

For a minimal working sample, try this:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "title",
    "description": "descriptor",
    "version": "0.1"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/sample": {
      "post": {
        "description": "sample",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "sample",
            "description": "a sample parameter with an enum value",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "1",
              "2"
            ],
            "required": true
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful request."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To test it locally, you can declare a variable (for example `spec`) in your javascript, and pass it into the SwaggerUi object.

```
  var spec = { ... };

  window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    url: url,
    spec: spec,
    dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
    supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
    onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
    ...
```

The `url` parameter will be ignored in this case.

Eventually, the output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi webron. Thanks for your suggestion. Still no joy with it... No matter what I try, I still can't get that nice output with all possible strings as in 'status' for addPet in example mentioned in question.
Since I'm following same JSON schema as per this demo json - http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/v2/swagger.json - could you tell me how should I modify Pet definition for status to achieve same result as online demo?

Comment: Which version of the UI to do use? When I tested it, it worked fine.

Comment: I'm using version version 2.0.47 and trying to modify json in this example: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist. If you could modify this json: http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/v2/swagger.json and throw it somewhere online I'd appreciate it

Comment: You're looking at the wrong file. Check swagger-ui.js instead.

Comment: My bad - version is 2.1.0-alpha.7 which seems to be the latest. Are you able to define enum in that github example ?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Let me know if it helps. If you need a sample with the pet store, I can do that as well.

Comment: Thanks webron. It is not what we hope to get. Example with possible enum values in Model that is available in demo is much nicer. thanks for your effort anyway

Comment: Okay, I looked at the edit you suggested, and now the question is clearer (probably would have been better to edit the original question and specifically mention it relates to models). In any case, this is indeed a regression in the UI and to solve it, you should open an issue on the swagger-ui repository.

Comment: Thanks webron for all you help!

Answer (score 32):

Updating this with YAML syntax.

OpenAPI 2.0:

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: sample
    description: a sample parameter with an enum value
    type: string
    enum:
      - 1
      - 2
    required: true
```

OpenAPI 3.0:

```yaml
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: sample
    description: a sample parameter with an enum value
    schema:
      type: string
      enum:
        - 1
        - 2
    required: true
```

Comment: Must it be of `type: string` even if the values are integers?

Comment: Nope. I defined the field as of type string in those examples, but you don't need to, if you would like them to be something else.

Answer (score -2):

This should work:

```
{
    "name": "bookingType",
    "in": "path",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "enum": [
            "packages", "accommodations"
        ]
    },
    "description": "lorem ipsum"
}
```

Reference https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#itemsObject

Comment: That's actually not a valid definition. The "items" object *has* to have a "type" property in it to be valid. In your example, `"type": "string"` would be fitting.

Answer (score -3):

This isn't the exact answer, but it might work for you until they add this functionality.

Simply declare the property like so

```
"MyObject":{
   "properties":{
      "MyEnum":{
         "type":"Value1 or Value2 or Value3"
      }
   }
}
```

Your ModelSchema will show `{}`, but The Model will show `MyEnum(Value1 or Value2 or Value3, optional)`

Comment: This is not a valid syntax for `type` in OpenAPI/Swagger.