# List of possible values for API query parameter in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

When documenting an API, is there a way to provide a list of possible values?  Something like this:

```
{
  "name": "propertyType",
  "in": "query",
  "description": "Type of home",
  "required": false,
  "type": "list",
  "listValues": ["singleFamilyHome", "condo", "farm", …]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define enum in swagger.io?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603871/how-to-define-enum-in-swagger-io)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In swagger 2.0 you can use enum:

```
{
  "name": "propertyType",
  "in": "query",
  "description": "Type of home",
  "required": false,
  "type": "list",
  "enum": ["singleFamilyHome", "condo", "farm"]
}
```

You ca find more info here: [How to define enum in swagger.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603871/how-to-define-enum-in-swagger-io)