# How to serialize string inside object as valid json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonserializer

Example:
I have 3 classes

```
    public class A
    {
        public int id;
        public string data;
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int id;
        public List<C> data;
    }

    public class C
    {
        public int test;
    }
```

Usage:

```
    var a = new A
    {
        id = 21,
        data = "[{\"test\": 123}]"
    };

    var text = JsonSerializer.Serialize(a);

    var c = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<B>(text);
```

Class A i'm using to store data in DynamoDb, class B and C as a return type;

How to properly map json array inside json to class B
I were trying to use default JsonSerializer and NewtonsoftJson, but both of them threw exceptions

Comment: Add `[JsonConverter(typeof(EmbeddedLiteralConverter<List<C>>))]` to `Data` where `EmbeddedLiteralConverter<T>` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51850391/3744182) to [How to escape embedded JSON after unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51845381/3744182).  or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39154630/3744182) to [How do I convert an escaped JSON string within a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39154043/3744182) if you only need deserialization.  In fact I think this is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: Or, for System.Text.Json see [How do I deserialize a nested JSON object which is a string in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69506159/3744182).  It's unclear from your question which you want to use.

Comment: @dbc First of all, thank you a lot. You really help me. And yes, it's a duplication. Sorry for that! I have created a flag for duplication.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  But, which one answered your question?  The Json.NET or System.Text.Json questions?

Comment: System.Text.Json

Answer (score -1):

should be somethinq like this

```
var c=new C(){ test=..};
var b=new B() { id=.., data= new List<C>{c}};

 var a = new A
    {
        id = b.Id,
        data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(b.data)
    };
```

or maybe this ( it is really hard to understand what do you want)

```
var b= new B
{
     it= a.Id,
     data=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<C>>(a.data)
}
```

Comment: Hi, we have found out that this question is a duplicate. 
Sorry for that.
PS:
If you are looking for an answer check the comments :)