# c# How to remove unnecessary " in a json string

Tags: c#, json

when use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str)` to parse a json string, the `playerInfo` parsed as string, how to remove the `"` in the start and the end of playerInfo so it can be parsed as object?
[image]

below link is the full json
[text](http://jxxupdate.kadtronics.com/text.txt)

Comment: Can't you fix the code which created this JSON?

Comment: no I don't own the Json creation code

Comment: Not just the start and end quotes, you would also need to unescape the internal quotes

Comment: Maybe a two-step process: 1) deserialize as-is, keeping playerInfo as string; 2) deserialize that playerInfo

Comment: How about deserializing it like you did for the surrounding JSON? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj.playerInfo)`

Comment: Assuming that `"playerInfo"` corresponds to some property `public PlayerInfo playerInfo { get; set; }` in your model, you could apply `[JsonConverter(typeof(EmbeddedLiteralConverter<PlayerInfo>))]` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39154630/3744182) to [How do I convert an escaped JSON string within a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39154043) or `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64640742) to [Deserializing stringified (quote enclosed) nested objects with Newtonsoft Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64640265).

Comment: Do those two answers answer your question also?  If not, please [edit] your question to share minimal versions of your JSON and data model **as text, in the question itself** rather than as a screen shot + external link.  For why, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
JArray jArr = (JArray)JObject.Parse(str)["pointList"];

foreach (JObject jObj in jArr)
    foreach (var prop in jObj.Properties())
       if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        if (prop.Value["playerInfo"] != null)
         prop.Value["playerInfo"] = JObject.Parse((string)prop.Value["playerInfo"]);
```