# Jackson ObjectMapper cannot deserialize POJO, throws an exception: No suitable constructor found for type [...]: can not instantiate from JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have tried to test the following code with no success:

```
class TestClass
{
  private class ND2Customer
  {
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String email;
    public Boolean multiuser;

    public String dnszone;
    public String uri;
    public String type;

    public ND2Customer()
    {

    }
  }

  @Test
  public void TestJackson() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
  {
    String json="{\"description\": \"test1u\", \"dnszone\": \"test1.public.sevenltest.example.com.\", \"uri\": \"http://199.127.129.69/customer/test1\", \"multiuser\": true, \"type\": \"2.0.3-3146\", \"email\": \"test1@com.com\", \"name\": \"test1\"}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    ND2Customer casted=mapper.readValue(json, ND2Customer.class);

    String castedback=mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(casted);
    System.out.println(castedback);
  } 
}
```

This problem is different from this one: 
[Deserializing JSON with Jackson - Why JsonMappingException "No suitable constructor"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367445/deserializing-json-with-jackson-why-jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-construc)

and this one:
[JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ]: can not instantiate from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625783/jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-simple-type-class)

and this one:
[JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ]: can not instantiate from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625783/jsonmappingexception-no-suitable-constructor-found-for-type-simple-type-class)

as I have manually override the default constructor, and its not a subclass.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Make it static. Jackson can not deserialize to inner classes

Comment: Thanks, it works. Your solution perfectly makes sense, as Jackson mapper cannot initialize an inner class and return it.

Comment: Minor addition: Jackson can actually deserialize one kind of non-static inner classes -- those referenced directly by the parent class. But this is not the case here, as Test class is not being serialized. In this case non-staticness was probably accidental.

Comment: I would bet most of the "No suitable constructor" issues with nested POJOs are because of forgetting to mark it static.  Thanks eugen!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that Jackson can't properly reach your `ND2Customer` class to invoke its constructor because it is `private`, as your class otherwise looks just fine. Try making it `public` and seeing if that works.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that ND2Customer is a nested class defined right before the @Test public void TestJackson().

Comment: And changing it to public doesn't make anything different :)

Comment: “It is an inner class” was highly relevant…