# No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com…Deadline]: can not instantiate from JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, mapping

I have been fighting with getting my test data loader working with one element in my test json file.  I have tried adding default constructors and multitude of different ways around this but have reached the point where I need help.

> The exception: Failed: No suitable constructor found for type [simple
>   type, class com…Deadline]: can not instantiate from JSON object
>   (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable
>   type information?)\n at [Source:
>   sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@1d7041fb;
>   line: 14, column: 4] (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]->com….core.domain.representation.AdmissionsRepresentation[\"deadlines\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])"}

The json looks like this:

```
[
      {
       "id" : "d5b6754a-f8aa-49e5-8e8c-d3f7ad0df2e3",
        "rec" : 5153,
        "acc" : 1389,
        "app" : 12,
        "rate" : 66,
        "sat" : 2100,
        "act" : 31,
        "gpa" : 4.0,
        "deadlines" : [
            {
                "type" : "Priority",
                "day" : "1",
                "month" : "3"   
            },
            {
                "type" : "General",
                "day" : "15",
                "month" : "7"   
            }
        ]
      },
      {
       "id" : "d5b6754a-f8aa-49e5-8e8c-d3f7ad0df2e3",
        "rec" : 5153,
        "acc" : 1389,
        "app" : 12,
        "rate" : 66,
        "sat" : 2100,
        "act" : 31,
        "gpa" : 4.0,
        "deadlines" : [
            {
                "type" : "Priority",
                "day" : "1",
                "month" : "3"   
            },
            {
                "type" : "General",
                "day" : "15",
                "month" : "7"   
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Snippets of the two classes referred to in the error

```html
public class AdmissionsRepresentation {
    private String id;
    private String created;
    private String lastModified;
    private List<Deadline> deadlines = new ArrayList<>();

  public AdmissionsRepresentation() {
    
  }

    public AdmissionsRepresentation(Admissions admissions) {
        this();
        fromDomain(admissions);
    }

    ....

    public void fromDomain(Admissions admissions) {
        setId(admissions.collegeId());

        List<Deadline> dl = admissions.deadlines();
        for (int i = 0; i < dl.size(); i++) {
            deadlines.add(dl.get(i));
        }
    }

    public Admissions toDomain() {
        ArrayList<Deadline> domainDeadlines = new ArrayList<Deadline>();
        for (int i = 0; i < deadlines.size(); i++) {
            domainDeadlines.add(deadlines.get(i));
        }

        Admissions admissions = null;
        admissions = new AdmissionsBuilder().setId(this.id)...
  .setDeadlines(domainDeadlines).build();
        return admissions;
    }


    public class Deadline implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        // private Type type;
        private String type;
        private String label;
        private String day;
        private String month;

        /*
         * public enum Type {
       
         * }
         */
        //NOTE: I have tried removing this constructor and it seems to make no difference.
        public Deadline() {

        }

        public Deadline(String type, String day, String month) {
            this.type = type;
            this.day = day;
            this.month = month;
        }

        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            System.out.println("setting type");
            System.out.println("type: " + type.toString());
            this.type = type;
            // this.type = Type.valueOf(type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your `AdmissionsRepresentation` class have a parameterless constructor? You haven't shown the constructors of that class...

Comment: Please edit it into the question.

Comment: Added a bit more of the AdmissionsRepresentation class

Comment: You're missing a `static` declaration of you inner class `Deadline`. Similar questions were asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916774/jackson-objectmapper-cannot-deserialize-pojo-throws-an-exception-no-suitable-c

Comment: Except Deadline isn't nested into AdmissionsRepresentation.  Are you suggesting changing   private List<Deadline> deadlines = new ArrayList<>();       to      private static List<Deadline> deadlines = new ArrayList<>();  ?

Comment: @RNYAH No, I'm not suggesting this change. I just wrongly assumed from your listing that the  `Deadline` class is nested. Please disregard my suggestion if it's not.

Comment: That's a reasonable assumption given the way the code is laid out. What would be helpful here is a [mcve].